# Delete visual studio 2019 extension settings

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

Don't suppose anyone knows how to find and delete settings for an extension in VS 2019. I uninstalled one and reinstalled and it was already populated with its previous settings. Its seems surprisingly difficult to pinpoint for some reason.

Just to add to this, I have found out that extensions utilise an options page. Now just to work out where Visual Studio stores all the data entered in an options page.

Comment: A Visual Studio extension can store its settings outside VS, e.g. in a file or registry.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov With that bit of information i have found out about the bin file in the user area which needs loading in to regedit to modify settings. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
With help from Sergey I have located the settings. They are present in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\"Current version"\privateregistry.bin

To access the keys you need to load the file in regedit(as admin). Then click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and File -> Load Hive and navigate to the bin file and type the name of the Key you want it to load as e.g "VSSettings". Then you can navigate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\"VSSettings" to find settings.

**Don't** forgot to unload HIVE after as you won't be able to open Visual studio without unloading it first.